# Copy a branch to a different Git repository in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a Git repository "Repository_A" with an existing branch "MF_Dev", where I am currently connected in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

How can I copy this existing branch into the new repository "Repository_work"?

The both repositorys are under the same organization.

[image]

I would like to do that connection either in Visual Studio Code or in Azure DevOPS.

The new repository "Repository_work" already has a branch inside. I want to copy the full branch "MF_Dev" into a new branch "MF_Dev".

I want to add all the code from today into the new branch. After that I will work in the new branch and delete the old one.

New branch with empty code:
[image]

Old branch with code I want to copy to the new branch and afterwards delete that branch:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this information can help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384642/how-to-copy-a-branch-from-one-github-repository-to-another

Comment: I found that post and don't understand it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "copy a branch"? How are Repository_A and Repository_work related?

Comment: Do you know how you can do this without Visual Studio Code? (i.e. do you have a Git question or a VS Code question)

Comment: As @mkrieger1 explained, it is unclear what you mean by "copy this branch into new repository"? Do you want to copy the branch into an existing repository? What does this repository contain? Or do you want a new, fresh repository containing only this branch? Or something else? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Do you mean that you want to copy commits between repositories? If so, which commits? Or simply add a branch label with the same name on an existing commit in the new repository? If so, on which commit?

Comment: It is a one time copy, after that I will delete the old branch

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Checkout to the source branch `git (checkout|switch) newbranchName`
2. Create a new branch `git (checkout -b |switch -c) newbranchName`
3. Add new origin `git remote add newOriginName originURL`
4. Push the data to new repo `git push newOriginName newbranchName`